# Can't pause VideoJS player using centered big-play-button

Tags: javascript, css, video.js

I've changed the `.vjs-big-play-button` in my customized VideoJS player to be a 100% width and height semi-transparent overlay covering the entire video area. I would also like it to fade in and out when you play and pause the video.

It works but now clicking in the video area no longer pauses the video. To pause the video I have to click the small play pause button in the control bar.

VideoJS is using `display: none` on `.vjs-big-play-button` which removes it but it can't be animated in css. Is there a way to fade the big play button in and out and retain functionality?

This works but has no animation:

```
// Hide if the video is playing
.vjs-has-started .vjs-big-play-button {
    display: none;  
}

// Show if the video is paused
.vjs-paused .vjs-big-play-button {
    display: block;
}
```

This has animation but pause is broken

```
// Hide if the video is playing
.vjs-has-started .vjs-big-play-button {
    opacity: 0;
    @include transition(all 0.5s);  
}

// Show if the video is paused
.vjs-paused .vjs-big-play-button {
    opacity: 1;
    @include transition(all 0.5s);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it's working beautifully now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on David Mulder's comment, by removing [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) from the button after it's been clicked, you allow all following clicks to pass through and register on the video itself.

```
// Hide if the video is playing
.vjs-has-started .vjs-big-play-button {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

// Show if the video is paused
.vjs-paused .vjs-big-play-button {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't have understood without your explanation. It worked straight away. Pointer events is new to me so I'll read up on it.

Comment: @edwinbradford Sorry for even directing you at the wrong property (well, misnamed property), but glad you got it working :)